# How can I delete image multiples generated by wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, image, ftp, image-size

I have a client that is asking for images to be compressed per Google Insights. While i was able to knock most out no problem, there are some problem child images left behind.

They appear to be spawning from the main image source and creating multiple file sizes. When I FTP in, or use the file manager to delete, or overwrite theses images, the transfer is successful, but when I reload the FTP client, or refresh the file manager, the image I 'replaced' is automatically replaced with the original file as if nothing ever happened.

When I compress the main image down and overwrite it in the client, it does make a chip in the file size of the duplicate, but not much. So, my main imagine is compressed beyond recognition at this point.

The file sizes that need to be compressed are the ones that are 560x340. I can't overwrite these or delete them. Any ideas?

[image: FTP client screenshot]

Comment: Those file sizes are generated as these sizes are registered by your Theme. Look for add_image_size in theme's functions.php file.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress the thumbnail images for the sizes specified in your install are pre-generated to save processing power creating a resized file for every request - it's more efficient to server static rather than dynamic content.

The different thumbnails that you see on your server should be defined under `WordPress Admin > Settings > Media`, however you will only be able to change the options here.

These thumbnails were added by a theme or plugin using the [`add_image_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) function, and to remove them you will need to use [`remove_image_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_image_size/).

You will then need to regenerate all of the thumbnail images - I would recommend finding a plugin that does this, there are many in the [*WordPress Repository*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?type=term&q=regenerate%20thumbnails).

Unless you rerun the code that created the thumbnail sizes in the first place, you should only need to execute the call to `remove_image_size('thumbnail-name')` once, so place it in a file in `/wp-content/mu-plugins`, load a page, and then remove the file.

Comment: hmm interestingly enough my theme's functions.php file is missing the code snippet about images. I'm only have issues with 4 images, so I'm thinking about just clearing out the main image and reuploading it. I went into the media settings and set all image sizes to '0.'